# javascript height document auto adjust

Tags: javascript, html, height

I got an sidebar which need to adjust to the document size. This works perfectly, its this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() ); 

    });
    </script>
```

But now i got an form in my website which changes with javascript in size when you put in options. So with other words the whole document gets longer when you put in multiple options. But this script doesn't adjust to that so the sidebar just gets cut off when you put in more options.

So with other words is there an possibility to make this script adjust automatically or let the following script rerun the function when it returns:

```
<script>
        treated = new Object(); 
        inputNumber = 1;

        function addOne() {

            //Create an input type dynamically.
            var divElement = document.createElement("div");

            var element = document.createElement("input");
            inputNumber++;
            element.setAttribute("name", "input" +inputNumber);
            element.setAttribute("onkeyup", "if (this.value.length > 1 && treated[this.name] != 1){ addOne(); treated[this.name] = '1'; }");
            element.setAttribute("id", "productoptiesadd");

            var price = document.createElement("input");
            price.setAttribute("name", "price" +inputNumber);
            price.setAttribute("id", "productoptiesaddprice");

            var foo = document.getElementById("japroductopties");

            var htag = document.createElement("h7");
            htag.innerHTML = "Optie " + inputNumber + ":";

            var htags = document.createElement("h7");
            htags.innerHTML = " € ";

            divElement.appendChild(htag);
            divElement.appendChild(element);
            divElement.appendChild(htags);
            divElement.appendChild(price);
            foo.appendChild(divElement);
            }
    </script>
```

Hope some1 can help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not setting #sidebar height property to 100% in your stylesheet ? Is Javascript really necesary ?

Otherwise, just write a function SidebarAutoAdjust() with your first code fragment :

```
$("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() );
```

Then all you have to do is calling this function at the end of your addOne() function.

Comment: Yea the 100% doesn't work cause i got elements in the template that doesn't stretch with it. So with javascript i can take the true full height. And how can i make such a function?